# how to make changes after merging my branch into master?gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I did:

1. Created a branch from master
2. Made some changes in the code
3. request a merge to master
4. my request approved
5. Merged my branch to master

I realised that I missed to make another change, so on my branch I fixed the code and push into my branch.
now what should I do?
Should I create another merge request and then merge?
Or I need to change the previous merge?
(I dont need merge request approval this time)

Comment: Create a new merge request.

Comment: @RomainValeri in the gitlab UI? pull from my branch into master?

Comment: Yes, create a new merge request in gitlab UI from your branch to master. Before approving / actually merging anything you'll be able to inspect which commits you're about to merge in. You should see your last commit alone.

Comment: @RomainValeri well it shows there are merge conflicts

Comment: "I realised that I missed to make another change, so on my branch I fixed the code and push into my branch" No. That train has left the station. _You merged the branch._ That's the end. If you had done this really right, in fact, you would also have _deleted_ the branch. This branch is dead. It has done its job. Start over. Get on master, pull, make a new branch, do your fix, commit, pull request. (Or skip the pull request if you have special permission to do that; just merge.)